# jQuery keyup value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to display value of `<input>` into the `<span>` and when label become empty, change value of span to "Video title". But always i type something into the `<input>` and then delete it, the `<input>` still have "" value so `<span>` display nothing. Thanks for help. (And sorry for my bad english)

Here is my code:

```
$("#newVideoName").keyup(function(){
   var newVideoName = $("#newVideoName").val();
   if(newVideoName == ""){
       $("#newVideoNameLabel").html("Video title");
   }
});
<input type="text" id="newVideoName">
<span id="newVideoNameLabel"></span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#newVideoName").keyup(function() {
   $("#newVideoNameLabel").text(this.value ? this.value : "Video title");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gZPyQ/